# How to disable dir() in python modules?

Tags: python, security

I know dir() in python returns all the properties and methods on the python modules or shared objects.

For security reason our company needs to disable dir() on some specific modules or shared objects.

Can some one help me to disable it ?

Eg:

```
class Person:  
  name = "John"
  age = 36
  country = "Norway"

print(dir(Person))
```

Output:

['**class**', '**delattr**', ... **'age', 'country', 'name'**]

I need the output:

['**class**', '**delattr**', ...]

Comment: "For security reason our company needs to disable dir() on some specific modules or shared objects." this will not prevent your modules from being introspectable at all. If your security depends on your modules/objects not being introspectable, then you are doing your security wrong.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on *why* you believe this would necessarily increase security?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just override the dir function in your class like this:

```
class Person:  
  name = "John"
  age = 36
  country = "Norway"

  def __dir__(self):
    return ['class', 'delattr', 'doc', 'getattribute', 'setattr', 'subclasshook']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah, and you can still introspect the properties of the object just fine. `dir` is a *convenience method*.

Comment: Thanks again Niklas Wild, your solution works great for me.

Comment: Hi Niklas Wild,

cPerson.py
class Person:  
  name = "John"
  age = 36
  country = "Norway"

  def __dir__(self):
    return ['class', 'delattr', 'doc', 'getattribute', 'setattr', subclasshook']


Importing the above module on other class like below shows all original artibutes:
from cPerson import Person
print(dir(Person))

Now dir() is not overidning and shows all the attribules.

Also need help to override __dict__ 
print(Person.__dict__)